# Can anyone tell me what kind plant this is. The flowers are light pink

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I live in Bossier City Louisiana. I haven't found this plant anywhere else in my neighborhood.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably Talinum paniculatum, 'Jewels of Opar.' The leaves can be eaten in salads. Here's a picture:
[image]